# Css list-style-type decimal, numbering automation testing

Tags: html, css, selenium, ui-automation

I have a pproject based on js and css. I have a situation where i cave a numbered list as follows

1. Coffee
2. Tea
3. Cola

And i am achieving this through

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul.a {list-style-type: decimal;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The list-style-type Property</h1>

<p>Example of unordered lists:</p>

<ul class="a">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Cola</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine. But the problem now is, when we are testing this through automation, we want to check whether the list is numbered or not. But since the list is controller through css, it doesnt appear in the DOM.

Is there any way to test it. Please help

Comment: Does any answer resolve you issue ? If yes then please accept the answer by click on tick mark below the vote count on answer. So it can be helpful for others. If no then update your question with more details or feel free to ask in comments. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

what your trying to achieve via CSS is also something you can do by using  (as for order-list) by doing so, your automation script would be able to verify that it is an order-list by making a reference to the HTML tag.

```html
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<ol start="50">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: But in my case its dynamic.It could be number or bullets or anything else which lists support. It changes based on  configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getCssValue()` method in selenium to retrieve the css properties. In your case try

```
public boolean isListStyleTypeNumber() {

    return driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.a")).getCssValue("list-style-type").equals("decimal") ? true : false;
}
```